# SVR/SVM output predictions are very similar to each other but far from true value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, svm, gridsearchcv

The main idea is to predict 2 target output, based on input features.

1. the input features are already scaled using Standardscaler() from sklearn.
   size of X_train is (190 x 6), Y_train = (190 x 2). X_test is (20 x 6), Y_test = (20x2)
2. linear and rbf kernel also make use of GridsearchCV to find the best C (linear), gamma and C ('rbf')
3. [PROBLEM] I perform SVR utilizing MultiOutputRegressor on both linear and rbf kernel but, the predicted outputs are very similar to each other (not exactly constant prediction) and pretty far from the true value of y.
4. Below are the plots where the scatter plot represent the true value of Y. first picture correspond to result of first target, Y[:,0]. while second picture is second target, Y[:,1].
5. Do i have to scale my target output? Any other model that could help improving test accuracy?
6. I have tried random forest regressor and perform tuning as well, and test accuracy is about similar to what I'm getting with SVR.  (below result from SVR)

   Best parameter: {'estimator__C': 1}
   MAE: [18.51151192  9.604601  ] #from linear kernel

   Best parameter (rbf): {'estimator__C': 1, 'estimator__gamma': 1e-09}
   MAE (rbf): [17.80482033  9.39780134] #from rbf kernel
7. Thankyou so much! any help and input is greatly appreciated!! ^__^

[image: First Target prediction]

[image]

---------------- Code -----------------------------

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import load

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error 
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=3)


#input features - HR, HRV, PTT, breathing_rate, LASI, AI
X = load('200_patient_input_scaled.npy')
#Output features - SBP, DBP
Y = load('200_patient_output_raw.npy')

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.095, random_state = 43)

epsilon = 0.1

#--------------------------- Linear SVR kernel Model ------------------------------------------------------

linear_svr = SVR(kernel='linear', epsilon = epsilon)

multi_output_linear_svr = MultiOutputRegressor(linear_svr)
#multi_output_linear_svr.fit(X_train, Y_train) #just to see the output

#GridSearch - find the best C
grid = {'estimator__C': [1,10,10,100,1000] }
grid_linear_svr = GridSearchCV(multi_output_linear_svr, grid, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=rkf, refit=True)
grid_linear_svr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#Prediction
Y_predict = grid_linear_svr.predict(X_test)


print("\nBest parameter:", grid_linear_svr.best_params_ )
print("MAE:", mean_absolute_error(Y_predict,Y_test, multioutput='raw_values'))



#-------------------------- RBF SVR kernel Model --------------------------------------------------------
rbf_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon = epsilon)
multi_output_rbf_svr = MultiOutputRegressor(rbf_svr)

#Grid search - Find best combination of C and gamma
grid_rbf = {'estimator__C': [1,10,10,100,1000], 'estimator__gamma': [1e-9, 1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6, 1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2] }
grid_rbf_svr = GridSearchCV(multi_output_rbf_svr, grid_rbf, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=rkf, refit=True)

grid_rbf_svr.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#Prediction
Y_predict_rbf = grid_rbf_svr.predict(X_test)


print("\nBest parameter (rbf):", grid_rbf_svr.best_params_ )
print("MAE (rbf):", mean_absolute_error(Y_predict_rbf,Y_test, multioutput='raw_values'))


#Plotting
plot_y_predict = Y_predict_rbf[:,1]
plt.scatter( np.linspace(0, 20, num = 20), Y_test[:,1], color = 'red')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 20, num = 20), plot_y_predict)
```

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is that when people use StandardScaler they use it along the wrong axis of the data. You may scale all the data, or row by row instead of column by column, please make sure you've done this right! I would do this by hand to be sure because else I think it needs different StandardScaler fit for each feature.

[RESPONSE/EDIT]: I think that just negates what StandardScaler did by inversing the application. I'm not entirely sure of the StandardScaler behaviour I'm just saying all this out of experience and having trouble scaling multiple feature data. If i were you (for example for MInMax scaling) I would prefer something like this:

```
columnsX = X.shape[1]
for i in range(columnsX):

    X[:, i] = (X[:, i] - X[:, i].min()) / (X[:, i].max() - X[:, i].min())
```

Comment: hey @White_Sirilo, so before i load the array itself i did a quick check on the original X.  I applied StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) -> StandardScaler().inverse_transform(X) to check if i got back the original X. Wouldnt that means the StandardScaler is performed to column by column?

Comment: I edited my comment above because I cannot make it like a code here for some reason.

Comment: hey, i just tried it using manual calculation as per your advised but with different formula, and confirming it using SKlearn ColumnTransformer, but both yields the same result.